# .NET ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <startup>

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, .net-core

Here is the situation :
I created a project A, with an UI library called QmlNet.
I followed a tutorial, etc, etc. The project worked great. (The features are discussable)

I then created a project B, based on the project A, minus the UI lib, to integrate another one (Eto.Forms)

- I switched the `TargetPlatform`, from `netcoreapp2.2` to `net461` (I tried to stick with netcoreapp2.2 and the problem persisted).
- The `OutputType` changed from `Exe` to `WinExe` (I tried to stick with Exe but still have the problem)
- Restoring must be done via nuget (dotnet restore doesn't restore packages.config) -- here I don't use Visual Studio so I don't think i'm concerned by this one.
- Building must be done with `msbuild` instead of `dotnet build` (`dotnet build` doesn't support `CodeTaskFactory`)

Now, without including the new UI library into the code, and just running like that, i'm getting this error :

```
System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'System.Transactions.TransactionManager' threw an exception. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Error Initializing the configuration system. ---> System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException: Unrecognized configuration section <startup>
```

The file it's getting the error from is in `./bin/Debug/net461/myapp.app/Contents/MonoBundle/myapp.exe.config`

And the first 5 lines of the file are :

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.6.1" />
  </startup>
  <...>
</configuration>
```

The full stacktrace is here : [STACK_TRACE](https://pastebin.com/QZEnS41N)

The few lines of code that are interesting are here, in the `Program.cs`

```cs
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using B129.Database;
using B129.Database.Seed;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Data.Sqlite;

namespace B129
{
    class Program
    {
        public static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Dependency injection.
            var serviceCollection = new ServiceCollection();

            var connectionStringBuilder = new SqliteConnectionStringBuilder { DataSource = "B129.db" };
            var connectionString = connectionStringBuilder.ToString();

            serviceCollection.ConfigureServices();
            serviceCollection.ConfigureDatabase(connectionString);

            var serviceProvider = serviceCollection.BuildServiceProvider();

            // Seed database. Do NOT dispose dbContext, that would destroy our only dbContext singleton instance.

            // it crashes just below :
            var dbContext = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<B129DbContext>();
            await dbContext.EnsureSeedData();
        }
    }
}
```

ConfigureServices and ConfigureDatabase are extensions, defined right here :

```cs
    internal static class Bootstrapper
    {
        internal static void ConfigureServices(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAccountRepository, AccountRepository>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<IAccountService, AccountService>();
            serviceCollection.AddSingleton<AccountsController>();
        }

        internal static void ConfigureDatabase(this IServiceCollection serviceCollection, string connectionString)
        {
            serviceCollection.AddDbContext<B129DbContext>(options => options.UseSqlite(connectionString), ServiceLifetime.Singleton);
        }
    }
```

And the DbContext is right here :

```cs
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using B129.Database.Mapping;
using B129.Database.Models;

namespace B129.Database
{
    public class B129DbContext : DbContext
    {
        public B129DbContext(DbContextOptions<B129DbContext> options) : 
            base(options)
        {
            // If I comment this line, it does not crash.
            Database.EnsureCreated();
        }

        public DbSet<Account> Accounts { get; set; }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
        {
            AccountMapping.Map(modelBuilder);

            base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

As said in the comment, by commenting the line with `EnsureCreated`, no error is thrown.

The stack trace is very very weird, telling paths I don't have on my computer (I'm on a mac) and the error itself it quite ambigous, since `startup` is a valid configuration section.

I run all this on VSCode.

Is it an environment problem ? Or is it maybe a Target problem?

Thanks for reading.

Comment: I'd like to point that I've tried to stick with `Exe` and `netcoreapp2.2` but it won't change my problem. It hink it comes from msbuild but I don't know really why

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore` does not work on net4xx targets. It works only on `netstandard2.0`

I read that netstd should be part of the net47 but by upgrading to net471 it compiles but still crashes with some (not) random TypeTransaction error.

The solution I found was to stop using Sqlite in my project, since it has been 3 entire days i'm spending time on this.

Good luck to those who will have to face this.